# how to use javascript in jmeter

Tags: javascript, json, jmeter

how to use javascript when I send request to server and get response as JSON data. Then I need to use response data for check condition in javascript (JSR223 Sampler) in Jmeter and return data for new http request

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not a browser hence it cannot execute client-side JavaScript. However it is capable of recording and replaying JavaScript-drivern HTTP requests so it is possible to send a request to the server.

You can use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) or [JSON Path Assertion](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) (both available via JMeter Plugins) to extract certain bits of JSON response or to check it.

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for plugin installation instructions and some form of JSONPath language reference.

Comment: I need to check condition inside foreach controller for send HTTP Request. example > I got ID and type from data server response and I must check type == '1' then send request. But JSON Path Extractor or JSON Path Assertion can't do like that, you can suggest to fix this problem.

Comment: Extract JSON Object value into a JMeter Variable and add [If Controller](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) with condition like `"${VARIABLE_NAME}"=="1"`. Put conditional logic under the If Controller